# Set Vector2 in XNA

Tags: vector, xna, xna-4.0

this is obviously a noob question but in XNA is ...

```
Vector2 a;
Vector2 b;

a = b;
```

under any circumstances the same as:

```
a.X = b.X;
a.Y = b.Y;
```

?

Comment: The answer is... Yes. If you initialize `b` otherwise, it doesn't even compile.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant: can I set both components of a Vector2 with the call a=b? Or is after a=b set to the same adress as a which then would mean that if I change a, I also change b? Isn't this the case with classes?

Comment: So basically, the question is not about how to initialize a vector ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Vector2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.aspx) is a `struct` (which is a value type).

So, if you do `a = b`.

It means it copies the memory of `b` into `a`. It is equivalent to:

```
a.X = b.X;
a.Y = b.Y;
```

So, if you do:

```
b = new Vector2(1, 2);
a = b;
b.X = 5;
Console.WriteLine("a.X = {0}, a.Y = {1}", a);
Console.WriteLine("b.X = {0}, b.Y = {1}", b);
```

The result is:

```
a.X = 1, a.Y = 2
b.X = 5, b.Y = 2
```